# Get & register the logged-in user ID October cms

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend, october-form-controller

how can I get & register the logged-in user ID in a table, 
with October cms

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use this `Auth facade` to get current logged-in user

```
// =====> forntend
// Returns the signed in user
$user = Auth::getUser();

// now use
// $user->id in your code

// =====> backend
use BackendAuth;
$user = BackendAuth::getUser();

// now use
// $user->id in your code
```

### In back-end if you want to add current logged in BE-User id then

you need to add **beforeSave event method** to you **model** in which you want to log be  user id also in addition you need to add this `log_be_user_id` field to your **database table**

```
use BackendAuth;

public function beforeSave() {

    // check if we are in backend
    if(App::runningInBackend()) {

        // we assign the be logged in user id 
        $user = BackendAuth::getUser();
        $this->log_be_user_id = $user->id;
    }
}
```

if any doubts please comment

Comment: Thank you for your answer

but is it possible to do with the builder (RainLab) plugin,
if so how?

Comment: seems we can not achieve it directly by the `builder (RainLab) plugin`, we need add some code on our own - `you can add field using builder` then create model - after inside that model add this code. then every time user create or update record `log_be_user_id ` will be updated with the `current logged in be user id` automatically

Comment: thank you so much brother, 
you really helped me, 

it works